# formatting dates incorrectly, trying to understand the reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, date, datetime

sorry if this question is a little ... strange, but I am a little lost to what is happening and how to control it. What I need to better understand is the following:

I have an ASP MVC application that works with Linq-To-SQL and an MSSQL server. The application is an inside (office only) website, and I am mentioning that so it wont sound that strange when I say that we wanted to ignore browser language, culture, date, whatever... settings and always display the date in the format "dd/MM/yyyy". Always.

So, now that I am testing a specific form in the website I encounter something very, very strange.

The first strange thing is that the date is not displayed on the screen correctly. Let me elaborate, I have a simple view that gets some data, read from the database, inside a model. So, as I fought for sometime with teaching the datetime object to display in a certain way on server level (meaning giving it an attribute like [Display(..)] or [DataType(...)] didn't force the date to look the way I want, so I simply wrote the following:

```
<input id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="<%= Model.BirthDate.HasValue ? Model.BirthDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "" %>" class="text-box datepicker" />
```

However, even though I am specifically formatting the date to display "dd/MM/yyyy" in the input, it doesnt. When the browser settings are Dutch, the value inside this box is displayed with 'dd-MM-yyyy'.

I can somehow accept that, the browser is a smart guy(or gal) and identifies that the value in the box is a date and applies formatting according to the selected language settings. I don't know how to tell it not to screw with my dates, but I can get to believe that this is what happens. HOWEVER, what I am finding a lot difficult to accept is that THE Date formatting somehow goes back to the database. This sentance didnt really mean anything so I am explaining again. I have a table that has a few columns, one of them being a varchar(100). Super, and because of some very interesting designing, that field can contain text, dates and whatever. 
So, because the field is a string, and later on I simply display it in a paragraph and dont need to do the whole dance of casting it to a DateTime object and then formatting it back when it gets in the view (which works so perfectly as I previously mentioned) I simply save it in the table in the correct format (dd/MM/yyyy). 
Yea, but not really. My code would look like that:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;

db.EmployeeHistory log = new EmployeeHistory();
log.ActionType = 1;
log.EmployeeId = 1671;
log.At = date;
log.Context = "A TEST";
log.ObjectTitle = "Who cares";

log.EmployeeHistoryChangesSets.Add(new EmployeeHistoryChangesSet() 
     { PropertyName = "TEST PROPERTY", NewValue = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), OldValue = date.ToString() });

dataContext.EmployeeHistories.InsertOnSubmit(log);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

This is a of course a test, one that didnt make me happy at all. Because, if you are paying attention, there is a field in the database which is mapped to a string (varchar(...)) and then I am taking the Date, make it a string with the .ToString() method while formatting it into a "dd/MM/yyyy" format. So I am not using dates (well I am using a Date object to get the date, but I am converting it to a string) I am using only strings.

And somehow, for some reason that is truly escaping me, the string/date is saved in the database in the format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'. I really didnt expect it to behave in such a way. At first I was going to accept my fate, even though I was having a really hard time accepting that the database will take the liberty to format my input even though IT IS a string.

So, further testing showed me that the Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") method actually returns the date in 'dd-MM-yyyy', depending on the browser language settings. Meaning that if I change my settings and it works correctly again ("dd/MM/yyyy").

So, my question is, what am I missing? Why is the .ToString() method not formatting the date correctly? Is my analisys correct or am I up and to the right on this one? If there is a good reason for that (even though I cant come up with one), should I just create my own extension method for DateTime class and implement the formatting mannualy or is there a better way?

I am really sorry for the long post (again). I would appreciate some clarity, as the whole project will behave this way. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: It looks like that the datepicker javascript coming in between and adjusting the output. Try to output a separate textbox and you will see a difference

Comment: @SonerGönül the current culture is "en-GB"